# cassandra's key have more time stamp of value like hbase

Tags: timestamp, key, cassandra, hbase

I rcently have used cassandra.I want to realize that cassandra's key can show more timestamp of value like using hbase in command line or java API client.
I know that hbase can show a key with more timestamp of value,such as

```
hbase> scan 't1', {COLUMNS => 'c1', TIMERANGE => [1303668804, 1303668904]}.
```

I learn cassandra data model in detail,but I can't find any way to show a key with more timestamp of value in cassandra include command line or JAVA API client.